# How to get Latest changeset version from TFS using solution file in Cruisecontrol.net?

Tags: tfs, cruisecontrol.net

I am trying to set up a Build Server using CC.NET and TFS. In my current work place, the project files are located in different folders, not in a same root folder. We are using some legacy codes located in different locations which is shared on many projects. Solution file knows the exact location of all directories.

In source control section of ccnet.config file there's only an option to specify a working directory to get the latest version. because of that if any code changes to the directories other then the working directory is not updated and build get failed every time.

is there any way to get latest version of all folders specified in solution file and build using msbuild?

```
<sourcecontrol type="vsts" autoGetSource="true" applyLabel="false">
    <server>http://tfsserver/</server>
    <username></username>
    <password></password>
    <domain></domain>
    <workspace></workspace>
    <project>projectlocation</project>
    <workingDirectory>workingdirectory</workingDirectory>
</sourcecontrol>
```

if I am going in a wrong direction, please guide me the right way to do it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get CruiseControl.NET to read your solution files and only update working directories used in that solution.  You'll have to manage the list of working directories separately in CruiseControl.NET.

If you're comfortable scripting, you could parse your solution files for the needed paths, and generate the proper, needed CCNet configuration file.

Comment: I guess you are talking about nant script. I am new to that. Anyhow I will give it a try. I think writing a script is the best solution instead of manually adding lots of working directory for each solution file. Thanks.

Comment: @suresh2 I recommend using PowerShell for scripting.  NAnt is old, barely maintained, and scripting with XML is painful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `multi` type source control:

```
<sourcecontrol type="multi">
        <sourceControls>
            <filtered>
                <sourcecontrol type="vsts" autoGetSource="true" applyLabel="false">
                    <server>http://tfsserver/</server>
                    <username></username>
                    <password></password>
                    <domain></domain>
                    <workspace></workspace>
                    <project>projectlocation</project>
                    <workingDirectory>workingdirectory</workingDirectory>
                </sourcecontrol>
            </filtered>
            <filtered>
                <sourcecontrol type="vsts" autoGetSource="true" applyLabel="false">
                ...
                </sourcecontrol>
            </filtered>
        </sourcecontrols>
    </sourcecontrol>
```

*UPDATE:* An alternative would be to use one workspace, and in turn several `<task>` calls with different `<workingdirectory>` and `<projectfile>`:

```
<project name "X">
    <sourcecontrol type="vsts" autoGetSource="true" applyLabel="false">
        ...
    </sourcecontrol>
    <task>
        <msbuild>
          <workingDirectory>C:\dev\folder1</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>solution1.sln</projectFile>
          ...
        </msbuild>
        <msbuild>
          <workingDirectory>C:\dev\folder2</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>solution2.sln</projectFile>
          ...
        </msbuild>
        ...
    </task>
</project>
```

Comment: I can try this. May be solve my problem. But I have 18 solution files and many working directories on each solution that I have to manually mention each workspace directory for each solution file will be a hard one. When we right click a solution file in visual studio and click get latest version, it automatically fetches all the latest version irrespective of the folder location. is there any way to bring that option into cc.net? or is there any custom plugin available to do this? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Your first solution Was useful. But not the second one. Thanks.